# Cannot access website using host headers on local windows 7 and iis 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, hostname

I have a problem accessing my website created using Visual Studio on my local pc.

The pc is using Windows 7 and a static ip address has been configured. I have added a hostname "192.168.0.1 hosts myweb.mylocal.com" on c:\windows\system32\driver\etc.

On IIS I have configured the binding myweb.mylocal.com with impersonation set enabled and windows authentication is enabled.

The user login just keeps prompting even though I have entered the correct username and password.

Comment: Are you sure that's your machine's IP and not your router?

Comment: Yes that is my machine IP, changing to another IP still didn't works login dialog is keep prompting.

Answer (score 0):

Yea 192.*.*.* is router reserved IP.

I had the same issues with Windows 7 and and its due to IPV6.

Try disabling the IPv6 Protocol in "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" and right clicking your stablished connection to your router, unticking the IPv6 and leaving the IPv4 selected to see if that will make a difference.;

Your local IP is more than likly :::1 or something along then lines!

-- Update

Where you have set you ip 192.168.0.1 to route to your local domain, try setting it to 127.0.0.1 so that it loops to itself and not via the gateway, Or you can leave it as it is and add the rule to your router to send traffic from the HTTP Port 80 to your PC.

Comment: 192. master net is not for routers only, I think you'll find the vast majority of computers behind *home* routers have a 192.168.x.x address.  I think you'll find 192.168.x.1 specifically is going to be a router/gateway 99% of the time (out of convention)...that's the part that makes me question if his address is correct.

Comment: Updated, Yea thats the kinda think i ment, Master net is reserved for a Local Network, meaning several PC's via your router will have an incrementing ip address that ranges from 192.0.0.1 to 192.0.0.254 if im correct.

Comment: i am changing ip on etc\hosts to "127.0.0.1" and use "myweb.mylocal.com" and still got the same problem, but if i change the ".com" into ".local" my username and password is authenticated and i can see myweb.mylocal.local website. is't ".local" a must for local development? for your info my machine didn't have any outside world connection.